# Change masterpage from Seattle to Oslo using CSOM, Sharepoint online

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, master-page, office-365, client-object-model

Using CSOM and c#, I would like to change the master-page from Seattle to Oslo.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `MasterUrl` and `CustomMasterUrl` properties of `Web`:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext( url ))
{
    var web = ctx.Web;
    var masterPageUrl = String.Format( "{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master", ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl );

    web.MasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
    web.CustomMasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
    web.Update();

    ctx.Load( web );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: how can i reset all subsites to use same master page?

Comment: The master page will have to be uploaded to every site collection and published. Then go through each site collection with the code in my answer.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158944/enforce-reset-all-subsites-to-inherit-this-site-master-page-using-csom can you answer this question which is on the same line?

Answer (score 2):

Changing Master page is very easy in SharePoint Using CSOM, we can give the Master Page URL in the web masterpage property, for reference u can check this link : [apply-master-page-using-csom](https://sharepointsolutions-sudheer.blogspot.com/2015/01/apply-master-page-using-csom.html)

Comment: is there a way to enforce "reset all subsites to use same master page" using CSOM?

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online - use Visual Studio. NuGet the following package into your winform or console app: Micrososft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Then use code similar to the below:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChangeMaster
{
public partial class ChangeMaster : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public ChangeMaster()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        var securePassword = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password)
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);

        securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
        return securePassword;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext cc = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://yourco.sharepoint.com/");
        SecureString secstring = ConvertToSecureString("yourpassword");
        SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@yourco.onmicrosoft.com", secstring);


        // The SharePoint web at the URL.
        Web web = cc.Web;

        // We want to retrieve the web's properties.
        cc.Load(web);

        // Execute the query to the server.
        cc.ExecuteQuery();

        var a = web.Title; // For debug checks.
        var master = web.CustomMasterUrl; // For debug checks.
        web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master"; // Or the original page desired.
        web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
        web.Update();
        // Execute the query to server.
        cc.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

}