# enforce "reset all subsites to inherit this site master page" using CSOM

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am able to change the master page using the below code

```
var web = ctx.Web;
    var masterPageUrl = String.Format( "{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/filename.master", ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl );
    web.MasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
    web.CustomMasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
    web.Update();
    ctx.Load( web );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This works fine and it changes the master page to desired file.

But the problem is after doing that i have to manually goto

> "site settings" -> "goto the top level settings" -> "master page"

and then check the **"Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting"**

Is there  a way to avoid this manual step and achieve this using CSOM?

Comment: Hey did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code.

```
foreach(Web child in web.Webs) {
    child.AllProperties["__InheritsCustomMasterUrl"] = true;
    child.AllProperties["__InheritsMasterUrl"] = true;
    child.Update();
}
```